# Is there a difference in meaning between 何時間寝ますか and 何時に寝ますか

Tags: grammar, translation

Is there a difference in meaning between 「何時間寝ますか」　and 「何時に寝ますか」 ?

I know that 「何時に寝ますか。」means "What time do you sleep?" 
But what about 「何時間寝ますか。」?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

何時間 is a question about a *length* of time.

何時 is a question about a *point* in time.

「何時に寝ますか」is indeed 'when do you go to bed?'. 「何時間寝ますか」 (or perhaps a bit more naturally 「何時間眠りますか」) is instead 'how long do you sleep for?'.

(寝る is 'go to bed', 'decide to sleep' rather than just 'sleep'; 眠る is 'fall asleep' or 'be asleep'.)

Time counter words with 間 in them I think universally refer to periods of time, such as 何週間 '(for) how many weeks'; though not all period-of-time counters use 間 (such as 何ヶ月 '(for) how many months').

Comment: +1, but 寝る can also mean *sleep*, so 何時間寝ますか is not unnatural at all. (eg. よく寝た! = I slept well!)

Comment: ^ I agree, we actually say 昨日は８時間寝た。 more commonly than 昨日は８時間眠った。 in normal/daily conversation.

Comment: そっか。覚えた！(*^ ^*)

Comment: (I wonder if I jump to 眠る since, as someone with insomnia, 寝る時間（つまり横になってる時間）は時に実際に眠る時間（意識を失ってる時間）とかなりの差がある(´・ω・`)

Comment: 睡眠 is also commonly used when talking about actual sleeping time: 睡眠時間